# npm: How to run several "watch" scripts in one command?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I have a command in npm's scripts: `"start": "gulp sass && gulp & http-server"`, the `gulp` and the `http-server` are both 'holding and watching' command, so when i use `npm start` , it's will hanging at `gulp` and not continue to exec `http-server`.

how could i run `gulp` and `http-server` in just one command? please help me

Answer (score 0):

There's a package called [`concurent`](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently)

```
concurrently --kill-others "grunt" "http-server"
```